# Facebook ads api - get stats by day

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I can successfully get campaign stats between particular dates via the API however I need that broken down day by date rather than a total.

I can see it works for the page insights API but there doesn't seem to be documentation on the ad insights API.

I'm using the following call to get the total between dates.

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/act_/stats?access_token=&start_time=&end_time=

However I cannot find the documentation to break it down into day by day for one  query.

This answer had a solution but didn't work.

[Downloading Facebook ads statistics in background (no web browser)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8724393/downloading-facebook-ads-statistics-in-background-no-web-browser)

Thanks!

===================================================

New info:

So I can use time_increment=1 to get a break down by day however this only works with 'date_preset' however I want to set a date range. I am using the latest API

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/act_{$this->accountID}/reportstats

Using 'time_ranges' will merge the data regardless of using time_increment=1

Using 'date_preset' eg last_28_days does work with time_increment.

Using 'time_interval' with midnight timestamps of my timezone (as the documentation suggested) throws the following error:

[error] => stdClass Object
        (
            [message] => (#100) The "time_start" and "time_stop" must be integer.
            [type] => OAuthException
            [code] => 100
        )

They are integers! Here's my complete post data

```
$postData = array(

         'async'=>'true',

         'data_columns'=>$data_columns,
       /* 
         'time_ranges'=>array(
             array(
                 'day_start'=>array(
                     'day'=>$startDate->format("d"),
                     'month'=>$startDate->format("m"),
                     'year'=>$startDate->format("Y"),
                 ),
                 'day_stop'=>array(
                     'day'=>$endDate->format("d"),
                     'month'=>$endDate->format("m"),
                     'year'=>$endDate->format("Y"),
                 ),
             ),
         ),
    */
         'actions_group_by'=>array('action_type'),




         'time_interval'=>array(
                'time_start'=>$startDate->getTimestamp() ,
                'time_stop'=>$endDate->getTimestamp(),
             ),

         //'date_preset' => 'last_28_days',

         'time_increment'=>'1',

         'filters'=>$filters,

         'access_token'=>$this->access_token


        );
```

Comment: Try using the current reports API instead (the /stats endpoints are very old and predate all of the current reports in Facebook's own interface) : 

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adreportstats/v2.2 - look specifically at `time_increment` which allows you to group by day

Comment: I am using the new API, I believe the new API is just a wrapper and it still calls the /stats URL. Not really sure where to put the time_increment in the new API call the documentation is not clear

Comment: When using 'time_interval' with 'day_start' and 'day_stop' I get an error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException' with message 'Invalid parameter' using their own example!

Comment: The /stats and /reportstats endpoints currently call different backends (though they're being merged at the moment)
What's the actual exception text you're getting? Invalid Parameter is the main error but there should be a subcode or specific text identifying the issue

Comment: New problem pasted above, I'm submitting to /reportstats thx

Answer (score 1):

Ok I had to change the format time_interval to the time_range format and it worked! The documentation says timestamps will work but it doesn't, this worked:

```
 'time_interval'=>array(
                 'day_start'=>array(
                     'day'=>$startDate->format("d"),
                     'month'=>$startDate->format("m"),
                     'year'=>$startDate->format("Y"),
                 ),
                 'day_stop'=>array(
                     'day'=>$endDate->format("d"),
                     'month'=>$endDate->format("m"),
                     'year'=>$endDate->format("Y"),
                 ),
                ),
```